# dependencies added in subprojects.forEach in gradle multi-module kotlin DSL is not visible to sub projects

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have multi-module gradle project with kotlin dsl called stream-data-processing. It is in github [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/stream-data-processing).

The `build.gradle.kts` file of root project is  -

```
    plugins {
        base
        java
    }

    allprojects {

        group = "streams-data-processing"
        version = "1.0"

        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
            mavenLocal()
        }

        dependencies {
            subprojects.forEach {
                compile("org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:2.2.0")

                testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
            }
        }

    }
```

`settings.gradle.kts` is -

```
   rootProject.name = "stream-data-processing"
   include ("word-count-demo")
```

I have some sub-project called `word-count-demo`.

The `build.gradle.kts` file for this sub project is  -

```
    plugins {
        java

        application
    }
```

But the classes in `kafka-streams` are not available in `word-count-demo`.

[image: Idea Compilation error]

when I did `gradle word-count-demo:dependencies, it doesn't show the kafka dependencies available to the sub project.

I don't want to explicitly specify the dependencies in every project.

What is the mistake that went wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It appears this would be adding the same dependencies multiple times. I think you need to flip it around and call `dependencies` inside `subprojects`, and **outside** of `allprojects`, like so:

```
allprojects {
    group ...
    version ...
    repositories ...
}

subprojects {
    dependencies {
        compile("org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:2.2.0")
        testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
    }
}
```